# Windows Phone 7 ListBox index operator

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, insert, listbox, indexing

I am trying to add Strings in a ListBox in Silverlight for Windows Phone 7. I want the strings to appear in fixed width columns, and for the ListBox to scroll into view when a new row is started in the listBox. Additionally, one word is added to the listBox at a time when the user clicks a button. I tried using a WrapPanel, but that did not allow for scrolling into view. Now my current solution would be valid, however the index operator gives me an index out of bounds error and the insert method gives me duplicate entries that appear on the next row down...

I am trying to use either the Insert method or the index operator (obviously not both) like so:

```
this.wordListBox.Items.Insert(numRows, formatRow);
this.wordListBox.Items[numRows] = formatRow;
```

This is an idea of the flow of my program, Example:
The user clicks a button and a Word is concatenated to the presently null formatRow and formatRow is added to the wordListBox at numRows which is presently 0. The button is clicked again and another word is concatenated to formatRow and formatRow is added to the wordListBox at numRows which is still 0. Thus, I now have the first element of wordListBox set to a string that contains two words. This repeats until 5 words have been added to formatRow and then, numRows is incremented and formatRow is set to null. Now, words will be added to the next row in the wordListBox, and the wordListBox will scroll into view because each element of the ListBox will be one string.

Can anyone point out my error with the insert method of index operator or show me how to make these functions work for my purposes?
Also, If anyone needs a better explanation I will try my best to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you could try to use an ObservableCollection to hold your items and then bind this to your Listbox-es ItemsSource, but directly adding to the Items collection works too. And to set focus on an item try the Focus method of the ListBoxItem.

[MSDN ListBoxItem Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

There are some great books from WROX, APRESS, MS for WP7 development.

[MSDN Code Samples for WP7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

[31 Days of Mango](http://jeffblankenburg.com/31daysofmango/)

[WROX WP7 books](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-400599.html?query=windows%20phone%207&filter=books)

Comment: Thanks! Where can I read more about all of these controls and "binding?" I am new to mobile development and visual studio.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus You are welcome and i updated my answer with a few links and book suggestions. For binding/WPF/SilverLight you could look for books too, and developer blogs.